# Meaning of "no day at the beach"

Tags: meaning-in-context, figurative-language

> Those kids are terrible and I am *no day at the beach* either.

There is no definition on the internet, but it sounds like "I am trouble."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

"Day at the beach" is being used as a metaphor for *something easy, enjoyable, and/or agreeable*. Your guess that it means 'I am trouble' seems roughly correct: the speaker is suggesting that the kids are behaving terribly but that his behaviour is also difficult for those around him.

It's similar to the second (idiomatic) meaning of the phrase '[walk in the park](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/walk_in_the_park)'.

Comment: I might add "easy" to your list of "enjoyable" and "agreeable." Excellent answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since I can't comment (argh!)...

I would ammend to @jfhc answer and say it doesn't necessarily mean you're in trouble.  It also can mean it's not as fun or easy.  Whether it means trouble or boredom is a matter of context.

A day at the beach means swimming, sitting on the sand, eating hot-dogs and potato salad, maybe a beer.

If you're working a shift on the checkout-counter at McDonalds, it doesn't mean you're in trouble, just not having fun. After all, it's no day at the beach.

Comment: Just to clarify, I didn't mean the speaker is *in* trouble, rather that they '*are* trouble'. I agree that working a shift at McDonald's is no day at the beach, but isn't trouble. However, for a person to be 'no day at the beach' suggests that they might be difficult to get along with, which can also be colloquially expressed by describing them as "trouble".

Comment: Alright, I can comment now!  So to address your concern, I said it "doesn't necessarily mean" trouble.  It could be someone who is difficult, lazy, etc., as well as trouble. I think the point of the phrase is that whether it is a person or a situation, you would rather be sitting in the sand with an umbrella-drink.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this term to describe a situation or person that might be challenging.

It is preferred to use **"isn't"**, but some people would use "ain't", which is non-standard<sup>[[(1)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ain-t)]</sup> English.

> - How’s your job?
> - It ain’t no day at the beach. (It is tough, or I don’t like it).

---

> - What’s it like working for your boss?
> - He/she ain’t no day at the beach. (He/she is demanding/grouchy/difficult to get along with/incompetent)

---

> - What was it like dating him/her?
> - He/she ain’t no day at the beach.

---

> - What’s it like looking for a job?
> - It ain’t no day at the beach.

Comment: Ms Jones, welcome to ELL!   As a word to the wise, this question already had an accepted answer (indicated by the green checkmark) but you are always welcome to add new answers if you have additional information to contribute -- just as you have done.   Be sure to check out the ["Guide to New Contributors"](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners?cb=1) and have fun!  Keep contributing!